# Android resource compilation failed-duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config

Tags: android, compilation, resources

Android resource compilation failed

**Output:**

> C:\projects\template\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:218: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
>   C:\projects\template\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:218: error: resource previously defined here.

**Command:**

> C:\Users\music7.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\b9713b2bbe96f34444d44f2bfbbdc6b8\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
>           -o \
>           C:\projects\template\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
>
> C:\projects\template\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
>   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #1

got this error plz give the solution

Comment: please post values.xml

Comment: values.xml file not available in project

Comment: Post the contents of C:\projects\template\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml

Answer (score 1):

This error took me forever to debug. But, at the end it all came down to whether you have made use of two "implementation" sources that do similar things. For example if you use a custom seekbar, from two different sources, both the seekbars will change the value of **tools:max**. This will cause the problem. It is the same reason why even you are getting the same error

> error: resource previously defined here

If you have used two different implementation which are similar, remove one of them or comment and check it will be solved